# doubt on radius of convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]
In this question I found by using the method R( rad of conv. )= lim 1/(a_n)^(1/n) an n tend to infinity to be 2e^2. Am i right?

Comment: No: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} ((n+1)^22^n)^{1/n}=2 \neq 2e^2$$